# what is the purpose of scrapy items since they are only dictionaries?

Tags: scrapy

what is the purpose of scrapy items since they are only dictionaries? I can send dictionary (or tuple) and process it in item pipeline so shouldn't I use plain dictionaries instead, or use `@dataclass` (since python 3.7) since it is more convenient?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; they're not just dictionaries (even if dictionaries were the only item type).

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

Comment: @MoeinKameli sure but I really don't see any benefit because dataengineering for scraping is often more than one line so all adapters/loaders are IMHO usless... any more benefits?

Comment: probably it doesn't have any functional benefit, but it provides more structured items. for example you can assign default value to them or you can use it in Django integration.

Comment: The linked documentation lists the benefit of each item type. If you don’t see the Item class benefits as worthwhile, just use a `dict`.